# Django - Overriding get_form to customize admin forms based on request

Tags: django, django-admin

I've tried various methods to achieve this.

I decided against overriding `formfield_for_dbfield` as it doesn't get a copy of the request object and I was hoping to avoid the `thread_locals` hack.

I settled on overriding `get_form` in my `ModelAdmin` class and tried the following:

```
class PageOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('title','name',),}),)
        else:
            self.fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('title',),}),)
        return super(PageOptions,self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
```

When I print `fieldsets` or `declared_fieldsets` from within `get_form` I get `None` (or whatever I set as an initial value in `PageOptions`).

Why doesn't this work and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to declare a fieldset somewhere in the PageOptions class just to see if that works?

Comment: Yep, That show's up no matter what is in get_form

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have no idea why printing the property doesn't give you want you just assigned (I guess may be that depends on where you print, exactly), but try overriding `get_fieldsets` instead. The base implementation looks like this:

> ```
> def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
>     if self.declared_fieldsets:
>         return self.declared_fieldsets
>     form = self.get_formset(request).form
>     return [(None, {'fields': form.base_fields.keys()})]
> ```

I.e. you should be able to just return your tuples.

EDIT by andybak. 4 years on and I found my own question again when trying to do something similar on another project. This time I went with this approach although modified slightly to avoid having to repeat fieldsets definition:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    # Add 'item_type' on add forms and remove it on changeforms.
    fieldsets = super(ItemAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
    if not obj: # this is an add form
        if 'item_type' not in fieldsets[0][1]['fields']:
            fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] += ('item_type',)
    else: # this is a change form
        fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = tuple(x for x in fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] if x!='item_type')
    return fieldsets
```

Answer (score 27):

I have some sample code from a recent project of mine that I believe may help you.  In this example, super users can edit every field, while everyone else has the "description" field excluded.

Note that I think it's expected that you return a `Form` class from `get_form`, which could be why yours was not working quite right.

Here's the example:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
        exclude = ['description',]

class EventAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Event

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return EventAdminForm
        else:
            return EventForm 

admin.site.register(models.Event, EventAdmin)
```

Comment: That looks really helpful. I'm in the middle of a deadline right now but I'll try this out next week.
PS Doesn't my super call result in a Form being returned? I'm just modifying the parameters and returning what get_form would have returned by itself.

Comment: And what about using fieldsets with this solution? If we use get_forms we seem to loose the configuration for fieldsets and also the DateTimeField javascript widget. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form seems to be much better solution. @ryan-duffield

Comment: I get an error: `EventAdminForm' object has no attribute 'instance'`. Django 2.1

Answer (score 8):

This is my solution:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude = ()
        else:
            self.exclude = ('field_to_exclude',) 
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
```

Hope can help

Comment: Rather than removing the field, you may want to make it read-only (Django 1.2 and up) - just use self.readonly_fields instead of self.exclude.

Comment: This is not thread-safe. Or it is thread-safe just because you have else condition. Try modifing kwargs["exclude"] instead of self.exclude.

Answer (score 6):

For creating customized admin forms we have defined a new class which can be used as mixin. The approach is quite flexible:

- ModelAdmin: define a fieldset containing **all** fields
- ModelForm: narrow the fields being shown
- FlexibleModelAdmin: overriding get_fieldsets-method of ModelAdmin; returns a reduced fieldset that only contains the fields defined in the admin form

```
class FlexibleModelAdmin(object):
    '''
    adds the possibility to use a fieldset as template for the generated form
    this class should be used as mix-in
    '''

    def _filterFieldset(self, proposed, form):
        '''
        remove fields from a fieldset that do not
        occur in form itself.
        '''

        allnewfields = []
        fields = form.base_fields.keys()
        fieldset = []
        for fsname, fdict in proposed:
            newfields = []
            for field in fdict.get('fields'):
                if field in fields:
                    newfields.append(field)
                allnewfields.extend(newfields)
            if newfields:
                newentry = {'fields': newfields}
                fieldset.append([fsname,  newentry])

        # nice solution but sets are not ordered ;) 
        # don't forget fields that are in a form but were forgotten
        # in fieldset template
        lostfields = list(set(fields).difference(allnewfields))
        if len(lostfields):
            fieldset.append(['lost in space', {'fields': lostfields}])

        return fieldset

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        '''
        Hook for specifying fieldsets for the add form.
        '''

        if hasattr(self, 'fieldsets_proposed'):
            form = self.get_form(request, obj)
            return self._filterFieldset(self.fieldsets_proposed, form)
        else:
            return super(FlexibleModelAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
```

In the admin model you define fieldsets_proposed which serves as template and contains all fields.

```
class ReservationAdmin(FlexibleModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['id', 'displayFullName']
    list_display_links = ['id', 'displayFullName']
    date_hierarchy = 'reservation_start'
    ordering = ['-reservation_start', 'vehicle']
    exclude = ['last_modified_by']

    # considered by FlexibleModelAdmin as template
    fieldsets_proposed = (
        (_('General'), {
           'fields': ('vehicle', 'reservation_start', 'reservation_end', 'purpose') # 'added_by'
        }),
        (_('Report'), {
            'fields': ('mileage')
        }),
        (_('Status'), {
            'fields': ('active', 'editable')
        }),
        (_('Notes'), {
            'fields': ('note')
        }),
    )
    ....        

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        set the form depending on the role of the user for the particular group
        '''

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.form = ReservationAdminForm
        else:
            self.form = ReservationUserForm

        return super(ReservationAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Reservation, ReservationAdmin)
```

In your model forms you can now define the fields to be excluded/included. get_fieldset() of the mixin-class makes sure that only the fields defined in the form are being returned.

```
class ReservationAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        exclude = ('added_by', 'last_modified_by')

class ReservationUserForm(BaseReservationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('vehicle', 'reservation_start', 'reservation_end', 'purpose', 'note')
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't change the value of self attributes because it's not thread-safe. You need to use whatever hooks to override those values.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, with Django 2.1 you could do the following

In forms.py

```
class ObjectAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        exclude = []

class ObjectChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        exclude = []
```

And then in the admin.py

```
from your.app import ObjectAddForm, ObjectChangeForm

class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj is None: 
            kwargs['form'] = ObjectAddForm
        else:
            kwargs['form'] = ObjectChangeForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_fields or get_fieldset methods for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could make `fieldsets`and `form` properties and have them emit signals to get the desired forms/fieldsets.