# How to hook the admin forms to get the request context?

Tags: django, django-admin

In [Django - Overriding get_form to customize admin forms based on request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/687829/541202) the problem is to select a different form based on the permissions of the user in the request object by hooking the get_form() method.

I would like to actually invoke a method on the object during iteration that uses the request context to output some information.

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) lists four ways to hook the form display.

But the function signatures don't include the request object.  If they did, you could write something like (note that `request` is not in fact an argument):

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display       = [ 'name', 'user_specific', ]
    #
    def user_specific(self, obj, request):
        return obj.func1(request)
    #
    output.short_description = 'UserSpecific'
```

Overriding `get_form()` would not be thread safe if used to store the state...  So what would be the best way?

Comment: As I ponder this, I expect that someone will point out that the user information ought to be put into the model with a ForeignKey.  That refactoring doesn't always apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I feel that maybe writing your own view is a better choice than hacking django's admin site.

But if you insist, you can override changelist_view and record the request.

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display       = [ 'name', 'user_specific', ]

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        self.request = request
        return super(admin.ModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(self, request, extra_context)

    def user_specific(self, obj):
        return obj.func1(self.request)

    output.short_description = 'UserSpecific'
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work (if you remove the redundant self argument for the bound reference).  It probably isn't thread safe, true?