# different fields for add and change pages in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django app with the following class in my admin.py:

```
class SoftwareVersionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("product", "version_number", "description",
      "media", "relative_url", "current_version")
    list_display = ["product", "version_number", "size",
      "current_version", "number_of_clients", "percent_of_clients"]
    list_display_links = ("version_number",)
    list_filter = ['product',]
```

I want to have these fileds for add page but different fields for change page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First have a look at source of ModelAdmin class' `get_form` and `get_formsets` methods located in `django.contrib.admin.options.py`. You can override those methods and use kwargs to get the behavior you want. For example:

```
class SoftwareVersionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # Proper kwargs are form, fields, exclude, formfield_callback
        if obj: # obj is not None, so this is a change page
            kwargs['exclude'] = ['foo', 'bar',]
        else: # obj is None, so this is an add page
            kwargs['fields'] = ['foo',]
        return super(SoftwareVersionAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 39):

This is an old question but I wanted to add that the add_view and change_view methods can be modified for this purpose:

```
class SoftwareVersionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
     ...
     def add_view(self,request,extra_content=None):
         self.exclude = ('product','version_number',)
         return super(SoftwareVersionAdmin,self).add_view(request)

     def change_view(self,request,object_id,extra_content=None):
         self.exclude = ('product','description',)
         return super(SoftwareVersionAdmin,self).change_view(request,object_id)
```

Comment: This is better and clearer in intent than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get this working in django 1.6.5 using the above solutions. So I tried creating forms and having get_form serve those pre-defined forms depending on if the object exists or not:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Project Name', max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField('Project Slug', max_length=255, unique=True)
```

forms.py:
from django import forms
    from models import Project

```
class ProjectAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    test = forms.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Project


class ProjectEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ("name", 'slug')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Project
from forms import ProjectAddForm, ProjectEditForm


class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # Proper kwargs are form, fields, exclude, formfield_callback
        if obj:
            self.form = ProjectEditForm
        else:
            self.form = ProjectAddForm
        return super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)


admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Now I can intercept the non-persistent test field in the forms clean and do as I wish with it, just overwrite clean in the ProjectAddForm:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ProjectAddForm, self).clean()
    test = cleaned_data.get("test")
    # Do logic here
    #raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a good idea to override `fields` or `exclude` or `form`, because they are config attributes, so they would not initialize for every request.
I think the accepted answer by shanyu is a good solution.

Or we can use the method from UserAdmin:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):                                  
    if not obj:                                                                                                 
        return self.add_fieldsets                                            
    return super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
```

Remember to assign the `add_fieldsets` yourself. Unfortunately it doesn't fit my use case.

For Django 1.7. I don't know how they are implemented in other versions.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it's done in Django 1.10. Just override `get_form` and return `add_form` when object is None:

```
class FoobarAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foobar
        fields = ['some_field',]

@register(Foobar)
class AdminFoobar(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form = FoobarAddForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(AdminFoobar, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

Answer (score 2):

This specific code did not work for me.
I simply change it a little:

```
if obj: # obj is not None, so this is a change page
        #kwargs['exclude'] = ['owner']
        self.fields = ['id', 'family_name', 'status', 'owner']
    else: # obj is None, so this is an add page
        #kwargs['fields'] = ['id', 'family_name', 'status']
        self.fields = ['id', 'family_name', 'status']
    return super(YourAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I got unpredictable results (it came and went at various times). I think changing self properties isn't threadsafe - see the comment on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687829/django-overriding-get-form-to-customize-admin-forms-based-on-request

Answer (score 2):

*dpawlows*' solution above is the clearest, I think.

However, I encountered an additional issue in that type of structure.

If `change_view()` makes changes to the model, e.g. specifies `readonly_fields` that have been filled in in `add_view()`, these changes persist in `add_view()` after `change_view()` has been called. For example:

```
def add_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    return super().add_view(request)

def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    self.readonly_fields = ['name']  # this change persists in add_view()
    return super().change_view(self, request, object_id)
```

In this case, after `change_view()` has been called on any instance, invoking `add_view()` will show `readonly_fields` ("name", in this case) set by `change_view()` and thus protect these fields from filling in.

This can be solved by adding a 'roll back' assignment in `add_view()`:

```
def add_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    self.readonly_fields = []  # 'roll back' for changes made by change_view()
    return super().add_view(request)
```

Answer (score 2):

With more modern Django versions (3.2 at the time of writing), you can override some methods from `BaseModelAdmin` to achieve having different fields on the "change" and the "add" model admin page:

```py
class BaseModelAdmin(metaclass=forms.MediaDefiningClass):
    """Functionality common to both ModelAdmin and InlineAdmin."""
    
    # ...

    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Hook for specifying exclude.
        """
        return self.exclude

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Hook for specifying fields.
        """
        if self.fields:
            return self.fields
        # _get_form_for_get_fields() is implemented in subclasses.
        form = self._get_form_for_get_fields(request, obj)
        return [*form.base_fields, *self.get_readonly_fields(request, obj)]

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Hook for specifying fieldsets.
        """
        if self.fieldsets:
            return self.fieldsets
        return [(None, {'fields': self.get_fields(request, obj)})]

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        Hook for specifying custom readonly fields.
        """
        return self.readonly_fields
```

For example, to add some read-only fields on the change page (`obj` exists), but not on the add page:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    # Readonly_fields only on change page
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:  # obj is not None, so this is a change page
            return 'field_1', 'field_2'
        return ()  # obj is None, so this is the add page
```

Answer (score 0):

Using formsets in Django 1.6 I ended up with the following:

```
def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        # It's a new object
        for field, fieldset in {'hide_me_from_the_first_fieldset': 0,
                                'me_from_the_second': 1,
                                'and_me_too': 1}.items():
            self.fieldsets[fieldset][1]['fields'].remove(field)

    return super().get_formsets(request, obj)
```

EDIT:
Perhaps a more intuitive way is to specify a separate `add_fieldsets` property and do:

```
def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        self.fieldsets = self.add_fieldsets

    return super().get_formsets(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use `fieldsets` for the Change Page and `add_fieldsets` for the Add Page.

Comment: base on django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin you can used  add_fieldsets .

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-admin-full-example add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.

Answer (score 0):

base django 3.2, you can try this

```
class SoftwareVersionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fields = ("product", "version_number", "description",
      "media", "relative_url", "current_version")
    list_display = ["product", "version_number", "size",
      "current_version", "number_of_clients", "percent_of_clients"]
    list_display_links = ("version_number",)
    list_filter = ['product',]

    # add 
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'description': 'add fields',
            'fields': ('product', 'description'),
        }),
    )

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets
        return super().get_fieldsets(request, obj)
```

learn this code from `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin