# Is there a get_form method equivalent for InlineModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to display different fields inside a class inheriting **StackedInline** depending on whether it is a new or an existing instance (i.e. add or change form). I know that inside a class inheriting **ModelAdmin** I can override the *get_form* method to achieve this as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321916/different-fields-for-add-and-change-pages-in-admin). Looking at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) it doesn't say that *get_form* is a shared feature under **InlineModelAdmin options**. So is there a way for me to display different fields for adding and changing in an inline? I am a novice. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because those work with formsets. Override [get_formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_formset) instead.

Comment: Does clicking _add_ call `get_formset`. I tried logging inside `get_formset` by it only logs for existing inlines when the page is loaded. Any thoughts on how I can change fields displayed on _add_?

Comment: Inspect the inline formset HTML. You will see that a hidden form of the formset has prefix="__prefix__", it is cloned and the prefix is replaced when clicking *add*. `get_formset` does not need to be called again.

To change fields for existing objects, you should alter the ModelForm instances in `formset.forms` which have `.instance.pk` before returning the formset.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have some pseudo code example or code example just lying around would you? Please...