# Dynamically excluding fields in inline django admin

Tags: django-admin

I want to exclude some fields in my inline based on my request user.

I know somehow I can handle this with methods like 'get_formsets', 'add_view', 'change_view', but I'm not sure what the syntax is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I achieved what I needed with the next code in my inline class:

```
def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.groups.all().count() > 0:
            if request.user.groups.all()[0].name == 'User Group Name':
                kwargs['exclude'] = ['field_to_exclude',]
        return super(MyInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

The answer to this question gave me the hints: [different fields for add and change pages in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321916/different-fields-for-add-and-change-pages-in-admin)

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `get_exclude` hook:

```py
class FoodInline(TabularInline):
    model = Food

    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        group = request.user.groups.first()

        if group and group.name == 'User Group Name':
            return ['field_to_exclude', ]

        return self.exclude
```