# Show different additional information in Django Admin change form depending on change or add?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible to show different additional information in the Django Admin change form depending on if an instance is being added or changed?

I am ***not*** asking about changing the list of fields.

I have an app that allows the user to SAVE BASIC SETUP (save a new instance) then SAVE ADDITIONAL CHANGES (resaves an existing instance with modifications), after completing both saves successfully, the user can click on one of three buttons to be routed to a different place. Everything works, but the user sees all the buttons all the time. I want to limit what the user sees so they only see the SAVE BASIC SETUP button until they have saved the instance, then after the save, I want that button to disappear and have them see the SAVE ADDITIONAL CHANGES button along with the routing options.
Is this possible? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321916/different-fields-for-add-and-change-pages-in-admin.

Comment: evergreen - thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that link deals with changing the list of fields that is displayed. I do use this method to display different fields in the add and change form, but I want to display different click buttons and associated text.

Comment: Okay, I understand. How are you implementing the buttons? Do you have a custom template? You can specify different templates for add and change.

Comment: evergreen - The buttons are in a form action group in the template and they route the user to a new page using the get_urls. The SAVE BASIC SETUP is an override of the _saveasnew in the admin, and the SAVE ADDITION CHANGES is an override of the _continue in the admin. I think I can control what is shown if I put them in an if condition in the template. I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364585/how-turn-fieldset-fields-in-django-template-into-a-string that if I can figure out, I think I can make it work. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: For anyone looking at this later, I did find a way to do this. I used the answer to the question from the link I mentioned above, and then I used conditions in the template based on a field that I included in the change form but not in the add form.