# How turn {{ fieldset.fields }} in Django template into a string?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

What does Django return with using {{ fieldset.fields }}? How can I make it a string?

In my template, I have this:

```
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
    <li> {{ fieldset.fields }} </li>
        {% if "nanoadded" in fieldset.fields  %}
            <li> nanoadded is here </li>
        {% else %}
            <li> nanoadded is NOT here </li>
        {% endif %}        
{% endfor %}
```

Here is what is returned:

[('arri', 'aconcentration', 'acat', 'anotes', 'agtlt', 'id'), ('nanoadded', 'response', 'select_charc')]
nanoadded is NOT here

So I am assuming that the fieldset.fields is not returning a string (even though it looks like a string). How can a make Django see the contents of fieldset.fields as a string? Thanks for you assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `fields` property returns a list that contains two tuples, so you might want to run it through a for loop to check each tuple for the membership of the string 'nanoadded'

Perhaps like this:

```
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
    {% for field in fieldset.fields %}
    <li> {{ field }} </li>
        {% if "nanoadded" in field  %}
            <li> nanoadded is here </li>
        {% else %}
            <li> nanoadded is NOT here </li>
        {% endif %}       
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Vasili - thanks for your suggestion, but when I changed the line <li> {{ fieldset.fields }} </li> to  <li> {{ fieldset.fields | str }} </li> the following error results: Invalid filter: 'str' Perhaps this the tuple issue you noted. I will see if I can figure out how to look at each tuple separately.

Comment: Django, at least by default, does not use `Jinja`, but its own [template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/).

Comment: Vasili - it is the tuple issue...when I look at each tuple in a loop, it returns "nanoadded is here" for the second tuple. THANKS!