# Get form fields list

Tags: django, django-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django - Overriding get_form to customize admin forms based on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687829/django-overriding-get-form-to-customize-admin-forms-based-on-request)

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm
```

In ProductAdminForm I create some dynamic fields, but in ProductAdmin I use fieldsets, so how can I get a list of ProductAdminForm fields?
I have found solution for dynamic fieldsets - http://jazstudios.blogspot.com/2010/08/dynamic-fieldsets-in-django-admin.html and now I want to do this trick with form fields. Maybe you can give me better solution?